# How to use if-statement in apply function?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, optimization, apply

Since I have to read over 3 go of data, I would like to improve mycode by changing two `for-loop` and `if-statement` to the `apply`function.

Here under is a reproducible example of my code. The overall purpose (in this example) is to count the number of positive and negative values in "c" column for each value of x and y. In real case I have over 150 files to read.

```
# Example of initial data set
df1 <- data.frame(a=rep(c(1:5),times=3),b=rep(c(1:3),each=5),c=rnorm(15))
# Another dataframe to keep track of "c" counts
dfOcc <- data.frame(a=rep(c(1:5),times=3),"positive"=c(0),"negative"=c(0))
```

So far I did this code, which works but is really slow:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  x = df[i,"a"]
  y = df[i,"b"]
  if (df[i,"c"]>=0) {
    dfOcc[which(dfOcc$a==x && dfOcc$b==y),"positive"] <- dfOcc[which(dfOcc$a==x && dfOcc$b==y),"positive"] +1
  }else{
    dfOcc[which(dfOcc$a==x && dfOcc$b==y),"negative"] <- dfOcc[which(dfOcc$a==x && dfOcc$b==y),"negative"] +1
  }
}
```

I am unsure whether the code is slow due to the size of the files (260k rows each) or due to the `for-loop`?

So far I managed to improve it in this way:

```
dfOcc[which(dfOcc$a==df$a & dfOcc$b==df$b),"positive"] <- apply(df,1,function(x){ifelse(x["c"]>0,1,0)})
```

This works fine in this example but not in my real case:

- It only keeps count of the positive `c` and running this code twice might be counter productive
- My original datasets are 260k rows while my "tracer" is 10k rows (the initial dataset repeats the `a` and `b` values with other `c` values

Any tip on how to improve those two points would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply count and spread the data. This will be easier and will work on any group and dataset. You can change `group_by(a)` to `group_by(a, b)` if you want to count grouping both `a` and `b` column.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    mutate(sign = ifelse(c > 0, "Positive", "Negative")) %>% 
    count(sign) %>% 
    spread(sign, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

package data.table might help you do this in one line.

```
df1 <-  data.table(data.frame(a=rep(c(1:5),times=3),b=rep(c(1:3),each=5),c=rnorm(15)))
posneg <- c("positive" , "negative") # list of columns needed
df1[,(posneg) := list(ifelse(c>0, 1,0), ifelse(c<0, 1,0))] # use list to combine the 2 ifelse conditions
```

for more information , try

```
?data.table
```

if you really want the positive negative counts to be in a separate dataframe,

```
dfOcc <- df1[,c("a", "positive","negative")]
```